# Where kernel configuration file is stored?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, configuration

I currently run Angstrom Linux 2.6.32. I intend to upgrade linux kernel from 2.6.32 to 3.0.7. For this reason, I had to configure kernel 3.0.7 running `make menuconfig`.

Now, I want to compare the new kernel configuration with the previous, but I can't find kernel 3.0.7 configuration file. Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your new one is `.config` at the top level of your kernel source tree. It may also get installed to `/boot/config-3.0.7` or similar, depending.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no `.config` file on `/usr/src/linux-3.0.7` directory. On `/boot` there is only `config-2.6.32` file.

Comment: @dempap /usr/src/linux-3.0.7 is where you ran `make menuconfig`? That should have generated a `.config`.

Comment: I suggest `find -type f -name '.config'` to find it, then. I definitely have one in my kernel source trees, through at least 3.13.

Comment: @dempap A `.config` is always generated in the directory where you ran `make menuconfig` (or any of the other `make xxxconfig`). If it isn't there, either you're looking in the wrong directory or you've deleted it.

Comment: `find` command found it: `./usr/src/linux-3.0.7/.config`. However, `ls` doesn't list it and it isn't visible at all.

Comment: @dempap try `ls -A` to see it. Files starting with `.` are treated as hidden (by convention).

Comment: you also may have `/proc/config.gz`

Answer (score 19):

Whenever you run `make menuconfig`, `make xconfig`, `make XXX_defconfig`, `make oldconfig`, `make localmodconfig` or any of the other `make XXXconfig` targets in the Linux kernel source tree, this creates (if successful) a file called `.config`. This file is used during the compilation of the kernel and is not erased unless you erase it manually or run `make mrproper`.

It's common to keep kernel source trees in `/usr/src`; if you did the compilation in `/usr/src/linux-3.0.7` then your `.config` file is in `/usr/src/linux-3.0.7/.config`. (Since this is a [dot file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_file), the `ls` command doesn't show it unless run with the `-a` flag.)

Many distributions arrange to copy the `.config` file into the package containing the kernel, and install it next to the kernel, e.g. `/boot/config-3.0.7` to match `/boot/vmlinuz-3.0.7`. Embedded distributions often don't do that; I don't know if Angstrom does, and anyway this doesn't apply if you compiled the kernel manually.

The kernel configuration can sometimes be available from the running kernel in `/proc/config.gz`. This requires the `IKCONFIG` compile-time option.